# update-initramfs Stuck

Tags: apt, linux-kernel, grub2, initramfs

I ran apt upgrade and it wanted to remove an older kernel. I ran apt autoremove and it got stuck at update-initramfs: https://hastebin.com/jegeyitoxi.cpp3
Here's the referenced log: https://hastebin.com/idayolugub.pas

I've tried running apt over and over. I've tried removing the rtl driver using the driver manager in kubuntu but it, itself, gets stuck as initramfs-utils hangs and i have to kill it. I don't know how to proceed. I know better than to reboot until resolved.

Comment: Please include the vital information about your question *in the question*, not on a third party site.

Comment: If you use ubuntu Yakkety Yak, there is a bug ticket <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1629235

Comment: Can you show `dkms status`

Comment: Try to re-install older kernel back and use dpkg to remove it manually.